# How to populate a JComboBox from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

I've got an ArrayList of objects, and all the objects have names. How can I populate a JComboBox with those names? I've looked online and found nothing so far. There are some resources, but they tend to go with a hardcoded version, which is useless.

Since I don't have any code yet showing what I'm doing, I can't attach any.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "names". Class names, object-specific private name Strings, or variable names?

Comment: Ah sorry about that. Variable names.

Comment: Variable names are close to worthless and in fact don't even exist inside of an ArrayList, since it holds references to *objects* not variables. Understand also, that many variables, all with different names, can refer to the same one object, and in this situation, which variable "name" is the correct one? If Marco's answer doesn't solve your problem, you need to give more information.

Comment: you create your own ComboBoxModel which wrapped the data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JComboBox` works with `Array` or `Vector`. You should use `.toArray()` method in the `ArrayList` to create an array.

```
String[] names = namesList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

then use `names`

Comment: This worked! However, I used 

String[] namesArray = names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);

Then by using JComboBox box = new JComboBox(namesArray.toString()) I got it to work. Thansk!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly feed in the items at construction time:
`JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(yourArrayList.toArray());` (you might have to check type parametrisation here)

JComboBox has constructors for Array and Vector as input. In your case it should be easier to convert to Array instead of converting to a Vector.

Or after initialization:

```
for (String item : yourArrayList) {
    cb.addItem(item);
}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html